# Best practices for folder structure for services in a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A react app has the following services (and maybe more will be added):

- ipfs
- web torrents
- web3
- indexDb

I'm not even sure those would qualify as "services" but I don't know what else to call them.

Current folder structure is:

- src

  - components
  - containers
  - css
  - reducers
  - settings
  - util
  - services

    - web3
    - ipfs
    - torrent
    - indexDb
    - api (this is the public api for all the services)

Does this follow best practices?

Answer (score 6):

There are so many different ways to structure a React App that it all comes down to what helps you, the developer, navigate your files more efficiently.

[The 100% correct way to structure a React app (or why there’s no such thing)](https://david-gilbertson.medium.com/the-100-correct-way-to-structure-a-react-app-or-why-theres-no-such-thing-3ede534ef1ed)

If you just want to see some example file structures, you are welcome to checkout many popular repos such as create-react-app or [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate).